# Do charges move on the surface of conductors for steady direct currents?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current

The answers in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109897/does-electricity-flow-on-the-surface-of-a-wire-or-in-the-interior) suggest charges move through the *bulk* of conductors, not only their surface,  when dealing with direct currents.

However, suppose we have a steady direct current, this steady state condition implies $\nabla .\textbf{J}=0$ within the conductor. Furthermore, conductors, by definition, satisfy $\,\textbf{J}=\sigma \textbf{E}$. From these two equations, we find $$\nabla. \textbf{E} =0$$

again, within the conductor. And since $\nabla. \textbf{E} =\frac{\rho}{\epsilon _{0}}$, we will ultimately have $$\rho =0$$

**inside** the conductor. This is in clear contradiction with the statement that charges move *inside* conductors for direct currents.

P.S. The reasoning above can be found in Purcell's Electricity and Magnetism, page 131.

Comment: How does charge density being zero contradict existence of current ? Electrons constitute current and charge over any volume is balanced by equal amounts of elections and kernels

Comment: You're right; a null charge density implies only either the balance or the nonexistence of charge in that region, the second option is obviously to be ruled out. The equation tell us charge does not accumulate inside the conductor.